# Prove equality of two intervals

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am working on homework assignments and need to

> prove the following equality:  $\{x:|x - L| < \epsilon\} = [L -\epsilon, L + \epsilon]$

First, According to the definition of absolute value, I get $-\epsilon < x - L < \epsilon$ 
and get $-\epsilon + L< x < \epsilon + L$. I know this set is a subset of $[L - \epsilon, L + \epsilon]$. But $[L - \epsilon, L + \epsilon]$ is not a subset of $-\epsilon + L< x < \epsilon + L$ since $-\epsilon + L$ and $\epsilon + L$ is not included in the interval. How can we prove the equality of this interval?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Actually the set is equal to the *open* interval $(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$

Comment: Alternatively, if your original inequality is $|x - L| \le \epsilon$ instead, then the requested set would be correct.

Comment: What you mean the set is equal to the open interval (L−ϵ,L+ϵ)

Comment: I mean $\{x:|x-L|<\epsilon\}=(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prove the equality as you wrote it, because it's not true.

What is true is $\{x:|x-L|<\epsilon\}=(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$ and $\{x:|x-L|\le\epsilon\}=[L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon]$.

Open [intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Including_or_excluding_endpoints) do not include end points; closed intervals do.